# Pseudo-metric space is a metric space iff it is a $T_0$ space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Pseudo-metric space is a metric space iff it is a $T_0$ space

---

we need to show that $d(x,y)=0 \implies x=y$.
i.e if $x \ne y$ then $d(x,y)\ne 0$.
Let $x \ne y$.Since it is $T_0$ space we can find an open ball $B(x,r)$ which does not contain $y$.
Then $d(x,y) \ge d(x,r)=r$ otherwise $y \in B(a,r)$ by definition of $B(a,r)$.
Am I right?

Comment: Not sure what $d(x,r)$ means, but other than that it looks good.

Comment: d is the metric of the given space

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct but you need to prove converse part also. Converse part: If d(x,y)\=0 (=r, say) for all x\=y. Then there always exist an open ball centered at x or y with radius r/2 i.e, d(x,r/2) which will contain x but not y. So it is a T_0 space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got the idea. A few minor fixes:

Since it is a $T_0$ space then *without loss of generality* we can find *some* $r>0$ *such that the* open ball $B(x,r)$ does not contain $y$. Then $d(x,y)\ge r>0$, otherwise $y\in B(x,r)$ by definition.